# Java For-Loop Error

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to print out all odd numbers that aren't multiples of 7 or 9. It works by seeing if the remainder is first not 0 when divided by two, giving the odd numbers.

But when I've put it to show the numbers if they are not multiples of 7 it just displays ALL the odd numbers, have I made a mistake?

```
public class NoMultiples7and9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {

            if (i % 2 != 0) {

                if (i % 7 != 0 || i % 9 != 0) {

                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like homework, so I'll just give a hint.  What does `i % 7 !=0 || i % 9 != 0` evaluate if `i` is a multiple of only 7 (e.g. 21)?  What should it evaluate to?  Get that working correctly and the rest should fall out.

Comment: It would print it because although 21 is divisible by 7, it's not divisible by 9 so I'd need to set it to when it's not divisible by 7 and not divisible by 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your inner if statement is wrong, it will cause all odd numbers that aren't divisible by by both 7 and 9 to be printed. I bet if you change your loop to go to 63 it won't print 63. The initial % 2 check is also not needed.

```
public class NoMultiples7and9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {

            if (i % 7 != 0 && i % 9 != 0) {

                System.out.println(i);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: on homeworkquestions prefer learn-how-to-fish type answers rather than giving away free fish.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code with:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i = i + 2) {
   if (i % 7 != 0 && i % 9 != 0) {
      System.out.println(i);
   }
}
```

Please note the use of the `&&` (AND) instead of the `||` (OR) and the useless of the `i % 2` because you can loop only on the odd numbers by changing a little bit the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use AND instead of OR in your comparison. In the comparison `i % 7 != 0 || i % 9 != 0`, even if i mod 7 is 0, i mod 9 may not be and vice versa.

Comment: on homeworkquestions prefer learn-how-to-fish type answers rather than giving away free fish.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {  
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            if(i % 7 != 0) {
                if(i % 9 != 0)
                    System.out.println(i);
            }

        }
 }
```

Comment: Isn't this solution a little bit ugly (I mean too unnecessary nested if)?

Comment: True but you're teaching very ugly pratice. To do 5 + 3 you can also use a = 5 for(i = 1; i <= 3;i++) a++; It works but you know you should not do this kind of stuff.

Comment: this is a homework question and this is pedagogically troublesome.